# Object-ID field in CSV file

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcgis-desktop, csv

I am displaying a CSV file in ArcGIS 10.  After adding the data table, I right-click it, and select "Display XY Data".

I am able to complete the required information and display the data, however, I receive the following error message.

> The table you specified does not have an Object-ID field so you will not be able to select, query, or edit the features in the resulting layer, or define relates for them.

Because of this, I'm limited in what I can do with the newly visualized data.

Is there a specific column that should be added to the CSV file that ArcGIS will interpret as an Object ID?  I've tried a few namings, but keep getting the same message.

Comment: I have met the same problem when I used arcgis. May I ask how to solve the problem? How to register my CSV into a geodatabase? Thanks in advance.

Comment: related: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/320979/what-requirements-does-arcmap-have-for-an-objectid-field-name

Answer (score 6):

Right click on the "X,Y Events" layer and export it to a geodatabase or a shapefile, whichever your preference. The OID field will be added in and all of those options will be made available

Comment: Is there a way to use an existing OID from the CSV file?

Comment: I would guess sort it by the original OID then create the new OID via export, and they should coincide

Answer (score 1):

It is very important to register your CSV into a geodatabase and OBJECTID will be automatically added hence be able to do what you intend to do

Answer (score 0):

My CSV file does have an ObjectID field as the first column, but still I received the same warning. I then exported the event as a shape, and all the values of the columns in the shape file are messed up when my CVS file has millions of rows, but the values look OK when the rows in the CVS file are not so many, e. g. only 10 rows.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).