# ArcMap says there is no Object-ID field, but there is, even after exporting data as shapefile

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, display, xy, objectid

[image]

Starting just a day or two ago, I have been running into the same issue every time I try to Display XY coordinates from a .csv file. When I add a .csv file, Display XY Data, I get an error that there is no Object-ID field (even though there is). I've even tried exporting the data as a shapefile afterwards, and I still can't edit any data in the attribute table. I can't figure out what to do.

Any tips or ideas?

Comment: I have run into the same screen when I display events and then export. I just usually go into an Editing session and have no issue with changing data in the attribute table. Is there something particular you are trying to edit or not following that field type?

Comment: Please always provide error messages as formatted text rather than pictures. That way they are available to be searched and easily read on all displays.

Comment: Try saving the csv file to a Excel 97-2003 workbook format (xls). I find that format more friendly to ArcMap than any other file.

Comment: Related: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/320979/what-requirements-does-arcmap-have-for-an-objectid-field-name

Answer (score 0):

One tool to try as a work around is the [Table to Table Tool](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/conversion/table-to-table.htm), this way you import your table directly into the tool and can format as necessary. I would format it as a .dbf, then try your process again to display X and Y coordinates. This method usually works for me when all else fails - I think it's because it automatically will take care of any strange formatting in your csv and will automatically [assign object IDs](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/manage-data/tables/fundamentals-of-objectid-fields.htm).

Answer (score 0):

If you are still having this issue, at the bottom of the "Display XY Data" window there is a check box that has the label "Warn me if the resulting layer will have restricted functionality." If you uncheck this box and then click OK, the error message will not appear.

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

After adding the excelsheet into ArcMap, Export the same to geodatabase (.dbf), this way automatically OBJECTID, OID will get created.

After that add that exported .dbf file into ArcMap then try it. It will work.